# sqlite Update not work correctly but not return error

Tags: bash, sqlite

Hi i have this script in linux mint 64  with sqlite3

```
#!/bin/bash

_Sqlite_UpdateRecord() {
    local database_name="$1"
    local NameTable="$2"
    local NameColumn1="$3"
    local ok_or_not="$4"
    local NameColumn2="$5"
    local symbol_name="$6"
    local query="UPDATE '$NameTable' SET '$NameColumn1'='$ok_or_not' WHERE '$NameColumn2'='$symbol_name';"

    #echo "SQL stringa $query"
    if sqlite3 "$database_name" "$query"; then
        echo "Aggiornamento nel database riuscito."
        return 0
    else
        echo "Errore durante l'aggiornamento nel database."
        return 1
    fi
}

_Sqlite_UpdateRecord "BinCexExchangeInfo.db" "ROBOTEST" "OkorNot" "1" "symbol" "LUNAUSDT"
```

but not  work i try also with sqlite browser and i tryed to execute sql command

```
UPDATE 'ROBOTEST' SET 'OkorNot'='1' WHERE 'symbol'='LUNAUSDT';
```

but  not return error

```
Execution finished without errors.
Result: query executed successfully. Took 0ms, 0 rows affected
At line 1:
UPDATE 'ROBOTEST' SET 'OkorNot'='1' WHERE 'symbol'='LUNAUSDT';
```

but if i go in table and do refrash not have  new data updated , why ??  here  you can download my database for testing https://mega.nz/file/OttAxB7C#qe5r28fxfNibJAvxgTrXzl7Y_xI88O4lmb-tLLgffPM

Comment: None of the rows matching a WHERE is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with valid identifier references in SQLlite but I'm wondering of there's an issue with the single quotes around identifiers (ie, table and column names):

```
UPDATE 'ROBOTEST' SET 'OkorNot'='1' WHERE 'symbol'='LUNAUSDT';
```

In the SQL dialects I've worked with it's common to wrap identifiers in double quotes or square brackets; this leaves us with 3 possible solutions:

```
UPDATE  ROBOTEST  SET  OkorNot ='1' WHERE  symbol ='LUNAUSDT';

UPDATE [ROBOTEST] SET [OkorNot]='1' WHERE [symbol]='LUNAUSDT';

UPDATE "ROBOTEST" SET "OkorNot"='1' WHERE "symbol"='LUNAUSDT';
```

Looking at some of your other questions it appears you don't normally quote your identifiers so I'd expect the 1st solution (above) to be sufficient.

**NOTE:** I'm assuming there's (at least) one row where `symbol = 'LUNAUSDT'`